# i uninstall pip and then reinstall pip but showing not installed

Tags: python, ubuntu, directory, pip

first i got an error due to pip version so i updated my pip to latest
version 19, after that again i got some error like "cannot import name
main" to fix this i uninstall my pip and then reinstall it. now it is
showing "The program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can
install it by typing: sudo apt install python3-pip" so what can i do
to fix this, thank you in advance

I tried "sudo apt install python3-pip" which show

> "Reading package
> lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state
> information... Done python3-pip is already the newest version
> (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4). 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 677
> not upgraded"

and when i tried to install package it shows

> The program
> 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo
> apt install python3-pip"
>
> umair@ubuntu:~$ which pip /usr/bin/pip umair@ubuntu:~$ which pip3
> umair@ubuntu:~$ pip3 install scipy The program 'pip3' is currently not
> installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install python3-pip
> umair@ubuntu:~$ cd Desktop/ umair@ubuntu:~/Desktop$ cd
> classification-master/ umair@ubuntu:~/Desktop/classification-master$
> sudo apt install python3-pip Reading package lists... Done Building
> dependency tree        Reading state information... Done python3-pip
> is already the newest version (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.4). 0 upgraded, 0 newly
> installed, 0 to remove and 677 not upgraded.
> umair@ubuntu:~/Desktop/classification-master$ pip3 install scipyThe
> program 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by
> typing: sudo apt install python3-pip
> umair@ubuntu:~/Desktop/classification-master$ which pip3
> umair@ubuntu:~/Desktop/classification-master$ type pip3 bash: type:
> pip3: not found umair@ubuntu:~/Desktop/classification-master$
>
> umair@ubuntu:~/Desktop/classification$ pip3 --version The program
> 'pip3' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo
> apt install python3-pip

Comment: If you run `which pip` instead of pip3, what do you get?
Also, `pip --version` does anything?

Comment: it shows nothing

Comment: Please reformat your quotation blocks into code blocks. It is very hard to read what you have posted. Simply paste the content into the question, then mark it and hit the Code Format button (`{}`), which will indent it by four spaces, keeping line breaks etc. intact

Comment: Is there any chance that you have messed up your `PATH` somehow? Could you check `echo $PATH`?

Answer (score 1):

When a Python distribution contains no `pip`, it can usually be installed with `python -m ensurepip` or `python3 -m ensurepip` or whichever Python you are using.